# Regarding complete backup and restore of Linux system

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, restore

This is regarding following:

[Complete restore of linux system](https://serverfault.com/questions/19881/complete-restore-of-linux-system?tab=active)

The selected answer has one line:

```
use rsync the entire thing with something like: "rsync -axvPH --numeric-ids ..."
```

Can I have the complete command?

I want to implement 1 day full and 6 days incremental backup.

Comment: How many servers?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use something like BackupPC to do the backups for you.  There are various other tools which will do rsync backups of this sort.

A tool like `mondo` can create aa recovery DVD or CD to begin a bare bones recovery.